# Why is the cat coming repeatedly? Why is it only yowling at our black cat? Is it just to fight?

Tags: cats, behavior

For 1-2 days now, there's been a female adult cat who's been yowling at our window. The only one that responds to her out of our three cats is the black male young cat (yowling through the window as well).

We have been chasing her away repeatedly but she keeps coming back. When we were going to chase her away again, we went out and our black cat followed. We were going to take him back in but they started yowling at each other again. This went on for five minutes before the adult female cat hit our cat and began fighting. I broke it up and brought our cat in.

My question is why is she coming back repeatedly and why for only our black cat? Is it just to fight

Answer (score 2):

Loud and persistent yowling is usually a sign that the female is in heat and searching for a sexual partner. If this is a stray cat and you want to avoid more stray cats in your area, keep any intact male cat away from her. If she has a human family, you should inform them that they can expect cat offspring if they don't keep her in the house for a while. Heat usually lasts around 7 days and the cat will be very persistent in her yowling and annoying everyone in the house.

Another sign of heat in cats is to lay the upper body flat on the ground and stretch the rear up in the air. Some cats do that around humans when being pet, but if they do it around other cats it's a pretty sure sign she's in heat.

Some amount of fighting between cats is to be expected, especially if they don't know each other very well. Even the act of mating is not a loving affair but involves biting.

Comment: My perception is that it involves grabbing or nipping rather than biting, but that's a quibble. "Love" is separate from mating in most species; trust is sufficient.